# mysql error 'NULL' at line 1

Tags: mysql, null

I got this error when tried to execute this:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NULL' at line 1

Can't seems to find what is the problem. Appreciate if anyone can help

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT (
      "SUM(IF(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(machine_stop)) = '",
      DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(machine_stop)),"' ,
      (machine_start-machine_stop)/3600, 0)) AS ",
      DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(machine_stop))
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  downtime_data
WHERE
  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(machine_stop)) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY;

SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT
                     failure_code, ", @sql, " 
                   FROM
                     downtime_data 
                   WHERE
                     p.machine='HH1' AND
                     DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(machine_stop)) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
                   GROUP BY
                     failure_code,
                     DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(machine_stop))"
                 );

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: change null to is null

Comment: Same problem#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'is NULL' at line 1

Comment: Print the `@sql` variable after the first select statement. There's a possibility if the `@sql` variable is still `NULL` after the first select statement then you will get an exception while executing `stmt`.

Comment: Or try to change in the main query like this: `SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT
                     failure_code, ", IFNULL(@sql,''), ...." `

Comment: Remove the `SET @SQL = NULL` entirely. There's no path through the rest of the code where @SQL will not be assigned a new value. If you must initialize it to clear old content, simply set it to an empty string.

Comment: how to print @sql variable ?

Comment: Print `SELECT @\`sql\`;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by any chance the `@sql` variable still holds `NULL` value after the first select statement then you are going to encounter an exception later on while executing the prepare statement.

Look at the following select statement using `CONCAT`

`SET @sql := NULL; SELECT CONCAT('abc',@sql,'def');`

The result is `NULL`. Although you might expect the result to be `abcdef`.

In order to get `abcdef` you need to do this

`SET @sql := NULL; SELECT CONCAT('abc',IFNULL(@sql,''),'def');`

You may try any of the following if it resolves the issue:

Either

1) `SET @sql := '';`

OR

2) If you want to keep this line `SET @sql = NULL;` then change the portion of the final query like this `SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT failure_code ", IF(@sql IS NULL, '',CONCAT(',',@sql)),`

Here's the final query:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT
                     failure_code ", IF(@sql IS NULL, '',CONCAT(',',@sql)), " 
                   FROM
                     downtime_data 
                   WHERE
                     p.machine='HH1' AND
                     DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(machine_stop)) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
                   GROUP BY
                     failure_code,
                     DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(machine_stop))"
                 );

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I think the error came from this 
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Comment: Execute this lines and you will get the same. `SET @sql := NULL;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`. That's what I've pointed out in my answer. By the way, have you tried any of the change mentioned in my answer?

Comment: `SET @\`sql\` := CONCAT('SELECT failure_code', IF(@\`sql\` IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(', ', @\`sql\`), ''))`

Comment: That's why I told you to use `IFNULL`. Probably I failed to make you understand.

Comment: `SELECT failure_code, FROM downtime_data != SELECT failure_code FROM downtime_data`

Comment: Thanks @wchiquito. Got the important part out of sight. Honestly I didn't notice it's you commented there. I thought the PO. Sorry mate!

Comment: @Wahsei Please check the query now. I've made a correction there.

Comment: Remember to remove the comma (`,`) after the column name `failure code`.

Comment: The comma (`,`) is removed now @Wahsei. Thanks again @wchiquito !

Answer (score 0):

I got it, there are no row from the query under this condition

```
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(machine_stop)) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

So it returned NULL

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue but let me share with you unique solution which I found out, I was working on 2 stored procedures simultaneously, on a new session if I run 1st sp I face this error but **when I run 1st sp after running 2nd sp** then the error is gone and I get my result.

It is something to do with mysql session variables which was getting set in 2nd sp and working for 1st one as well.